# firefox / chrome console log of functions

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, console, firebug

Normally I use ff + firebug and I find extremely useful it's console feature: if you console.log(a_function); you don't see the (IMHO totally useless) function body, but a link to the js source file where the function is defined.

(On https://getfirebug.com/logging they describe it in the "Logging object hyperlinks" paragraph)

but but, is there a way to have the same behaviour on the firefox / chrome "native" console?

Comment: just to be clear: I *don't* want the body of the function. I like what firebug do: show just the function name; if you click on it jump to the source at the function row. Is there a way to accomplish this in the chrome / firefox web console?

Comment: just curious: why do you need it? You don't like firebug?

Comment: I like firebug, but sometimes I need to debug in chrome.

Comment: you can modify Function.prototype.toString during debug, and by sniffing arguments you can tell if chrome inspector is calling:  if(  fnToString(arguments.callee.caller.split("We don't use String")[1]){ ... }

Comment: there's also firebug for chrome, firebug lite.

Comment: In Chrome at least, to the right of every `console.log` result it shows the name of the file and the line number it came from. If you click it, it shows you where in the source it came from.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome if you place your function in  the `console.dir` function, you will get additional information about the function. You can then right click on the function and select "show function definition".

Example:

```
console.dir(my_function);
```

I'm not seeing anything in firefox.

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down. It's not the exact same flow as Firebug, but it gets you to the function definition. ["Show Function Definition"](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94932) has been in Chrome since 2012-08-26.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `console.trace()` or even `console.log()` within the function definition to track it. Something like this:

```
function something(){
    var x = 5 +3;
    console.trace();
    console.log("FUNCTION SOMETHING");
    return x;
  }
```

So, when it shows up in your Chrome console tools, you can see the originating file and line AND click on it to get to that file's source. Not as eloquent as FF Firebug, but it's a start.

I don't know if you have access to these functions and just want an easy way of going from the console to the source file OR truly don't know where the function originates. But this is what I would do. Check out the source for reference!

Source: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletrace

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
console.log("test");
```

It will work on both ff and chrome.

Comment: this snippet do the same thing on firefox and chrome, but it's not what I want. I want the function definition, possibly clickable to go to the file where the function is written. I don't want a string.

Answer (score -1):

why not `console.debug(yourfunc.toString());`   ?

Comment: because yourfunc.toString() return the *body* of the function. I *don't* want the body of the function.

Comment: You're right Vito, I had to read further comments, because it was incomprehensible. Thanks for downvote!

Comment: how it was incomprehensible? it's the whole point of my question.

Comment: nope, it wasn`t You to comment first trying to explain what You was asking?